# Intersection of Cylinders of Simply Connected Sets in $\mathbb C^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

A while ago, I thought of the following question in relation to some other work I was doing mathematically:

> Let $f_1,f_2,f_3:\mathbb C^2\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be three linear maps and $A_1,A_2,A_3\subseteq\mathbb C$ be three simply connected open subsets of $\mathbb C$. Let $B_i=f_i^{-1}(A_i)$. Is it necessarily the case that
>   $B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3$
>   is a union of simply connected components?

I've had very little luck in considering this question or even with weaker versions of it; if we only had two sets or if we were in only one dimension, it's not too hard to prove a positive answer to this question. Similarly, if the sets were convex, the answer is clearly positive.

My initial thought was to try to get information about this intersection by looking at the Meyer-Vietoris sequence of pairs such as $(B_1,B_2\cap B_3)$ or $(B_1\cap B_2, B_2\cap B_3)$, but these sequences involve the homology of sets such as $B_1\cup (B_2\cap B_3)$ which I can only think to study by looking at the sequence for the pair $(B_1\cup B_2, B_1\cup B_3)$, which then involves the set $B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3$ which I also don't have a good way to understand - basically, I can get a whole web of morphisms between relevant sets, but never any results. I've also thought to try using something like Lefschetz duality, but this never seems to lead anywhere.

Another interesting approach is to fix a loop $\gamma$ in $\mathbb C^2$ and then look at the intersection of every such cylinder containing $\gamma$ to see if $\gamma$ could be contracted within any open set containing that intersection - but these intersections seem really difficult to reason about.

I don't have a strong sense of whether the answer is positive or negative - my work on the question leaves me pretty unsure of it. Is there a nice proof or counterexample to the question? I'd also be curious if, in the event that the answer is positive, whether the answer is the same for more cylinders or more dimensions.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but is this equivalent to asking about cylinders in the usual sense, i.e. inverse images under the projection to the first component of $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$?

Comment: @Conifold I don't think so - the cylinders don't need to parallel to one another and it's not the sort of question where one can sort push things around easily in the usual topological way. It does suffice (via careful scaling) to work with the case where $f_1(z_1,z_2)=z_1$ and $f_2(z_1,z_2)=z_2$ and $f_3(z_1,z_2)=z_1+z_2$ though - every non-trivial case (e.g. where $f_i$ are in general position) reduces to this one by applying a (linear) automorphism to $\mathbb C^2$ and scaling $f_1$ and $f_2$ appropriately.

Comment: Well, it is easy to imagine topologically deformed cylinders intersecting over a torus even in $\mathbb R^3$, so it must be something about linearity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Choose
\begin{align*}
f_1(z,w)&=z\\
f_2(z,w)&=w\\
f_3(z,w)&=z+w\\
U_1&=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \operatorname{Im} z<(\operatorname{Re}z)^2\}\\
U_2&=U_1\\
U_3&=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid \operatorname{Im} z>1\}
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}
B_1&=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb C^2\mid \operatorname{Im} z<(\operatorname{Re}z)^2\}\\
B_2&=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb C^2\mid \operatorname{Im} w<(\operatorname{Re}w)^2\}\\
B_3&=\{(z,w)\in\mathbb C^2\mid \operatorname{Im}(z+w)>1\}.
\end{align*}

If $(z,w)\in B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3$ then $(\operatorname{Re}z)^2+(\operatorname{Re}w)^2>1,$ so in particular $(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Re}w)\neq(0,0).$
Define $h:\mathbb C^2\to\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ by $$h(z,w)=(\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Re}w).$$

Define $\gamma:\mathbb R/2\pi \mathbb Z\to B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3$ by $$\gamma(\theta)=(2\sin\theta+2i\sin^2\theta,2\cos\theta+2i\cos^2\theta).$$ Then $h(\gamma(t))=(2\sin\theta,2\cos\theta)$ winds once around $(0,0)$ as $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi.$ This shows that
$$h^*:\pi_1(B_1\cap B_2\cap B_3,\gamma(0))\to\pi_1(\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0,0\},h(\gamma(0)))$$
has a non-trivial image, which implies that its domain is non-trivial.

Comment: Is there any intuition behind how you found this counterexample? It seems like this somehow makes $B_1\cap B_2$ into a set with significant concavity and then slices it across a "hole" with $B_3$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt: the choice of $f_1,f_2,f_3$ is basically WLOG. Then to lower dimensions I looked for closed 1D sets instead of open sets for the $U_i$ (just replace the inequalities by equalities in the definitions of $U_i$). I would like to say I then thought of using sets of the form $\{x+iy\mid y=F(x)\},$ but really I just plugged in the first non-convex 1D sets I thought of and played around a bit.